# XPending() reports error on window close

Tags: xlib, xserver

In a call to `XPending()` I get following error message in terminal:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
```

This happens after I click the close button on the window (the cross in the corner).

Otherwise the program works fine. I suggest when I click the close button, the window manager will abruptly disconnect my app from the XServer. So the connection is no longer active and XPending returns an error. Can I somehow check if connection is still active or not prior to calling `XPending()`? What is a recommended "good practice" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle [WM_DELETE_WINDOW](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.8.1) message that icccm-compliant window manager sends to client before closing it's window. After last top level window is closed connection to X server is usually closed by server.